# Signed URL result with random AuthenticationRequired

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, cdn, pre-signed-url, google-cloud-cdn

I have a CDN in gcloud configured with a storage bucket backend, the bucket is private and I give the `ObjectViewer` permission to the CDN service account (`serviceAccount:service-XXXX@cloud-cdn-fill.iam.gserviceaccount.com`)

I have an API to request files from a CDN :

- This API check if the user is allowed to download the requested file
- Compute a signed URL for this file using the CDN URL
- Redirect the user with the computed signed url

Most of the time, the client succeed to download file and receive `200`, but I have randomly errors when my client (mobile app) was redirected to the signed URL :

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code><Message>Authentication required.</Message></Error>
```

Generate a new signed URL didn't fix this issue : the error was sent during X minutes/seconds.

My API reply with `301` and didn't trigger authorization errors. This error was sent by the CND HTTP load balancer with a status code `401`.

Here is my function to generate signed URL :

```golang
func signURL(url string) (string, errors.Mwm) {
    expirationTime := time.Now().UTC().Add(internal.DefaultSignedURLValidTime).Unix()
    cdnKeyValue, err := internal.GetCDNSignKeyValue()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    sep := "?"
    if strings.Contains(url, "?") {
        sep = "&"
    }
    url += sep
    url += fmt.Sprintf("Expires=%d", expirationTime)
    url += fmt.Sprintf("&KeyName=%s", internal.CdnSignKeyName)

    mac := hmac.New(sha1.New, cdnKeyValue)
    mac.Write([]byte(url))
    sig := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(mac.Sum(nil))
    url += fmt.Sprintf("&Signature=%s", sig)
    return url, nil
}
```

Comment: This is hard to validate without URLs (which you may not want to share). Have you confirmed that your URLs are not expired / expiring, and that your server has synchronized clocks?

Comment: The AuthenticationRequired error suggests your client is sending expired Google Cloud Storage credentials in an Authorization header, and those credentials are being rejected by Google Cloud Storage. Do you have some logic in your client to send an Authorization header? Most users of Google Cloud CDN signed URLs don't send an Authorization header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** :

My API take an `Authorization` header to auth the user and check if he's allowed to download the file. But an HTTP redirection keep the headers.

If the CDN doesn't have the requested file in cache, the user was redirected to GCS and a 401 is sent for an authorization conflict method due to the `Signature` query param and the `Authorization` header :

> This error indicates a problem with the authorization provided in the request to Cloud Storage. The following are some situations where that will occur :
>
> - Multiple non-matching authorizations were provided; choose one mode only

[This doc helps me](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#401_Unauthorized)

I just change my `Authorization` with an other, and it solved the authorizations conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had Basic Auth in the frontend webserver.
When my actual site accessed files in the bucket which also routed via the Load Balancer as another backend, that header caused issues.